# Underlining list item with borders while hovering

Tags: jquery, html, css, border, listitem

I am trying to underline list items when I hover on like in this example:
[image]

But in this example they use images for underlining. I am trying to do this with **borders**. My menu is that:
[image]

When I hover on one of them, it becomes very interesting shape:

[image]

although I want to something like that:
[image]

My codes:

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="anasayfa-m"><a href="">Anasayfa</a></li>
<li class="yazilar-m"><a href="">Yazılar</a></li>
<li class="kategoriler-m"><a href="">Kategoriler</a></li>
<li class="sayfalar-m"><a href="">Sayfalar</a></li>
<li class="gorunum-m"><a href="">Görünüm</a></li>
<li class="yorumlar-m"><a href="">Yorumlar</a></li>
<li class="kullanicilar-m"><a href="">Kullanıcılar</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
ul.menu { 
    width: 62%;
    height: 11%;
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
}
ul.menu li { 
    float: left;
    width: 13.14%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.menu li a {
position: relative;
top: 70%;
left: 27%;
}
ul.menu li:hover {
border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
outline: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
ul.menu li.kategoriler-m a {
left: 23%;
}
ul.menu li.sayfalar-m a {
left: 31%;
}
ul.menu li.yazilar-m a {
left: 35%;
}
ul.menu li.yazilar-m {
background: url(icons/myazılar.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.kategoriler-m {
background: url(icons/mkategori.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.sayfalar-m {
background: url(icons/msayfalar.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.gorunum-m {
background: url(icons/mtheme.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.yorumlar-m {
background: url(icons/mcomments.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.kullanicilar-m {
border-right: none;
background: url(icons/musers.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wh = $(window).height();
    $("ul.menu li").hover(function () {
            var height = $(this).height();
            var heightp = (100 * (height - 4)) / wh;
            $(this).addClass("onHover");
            $(this).css("height", function (heightp) {
                return heightp + "%";
            });
            $("ul.menu li").not(".onHover").css("height", function (heightp) {
                return heightp + "%";
            });
            $("ul.menu li").not(".onHover").css("border-bottom", "4px solid #e1e1e1");
        },
        function () {
            var height = $(this).height();
            var heightp = (100 * (height + 4)) / wh;
            $(this).removeClass("onHover");
            $(this).css("height", function (heightp) {
                return heightp + "%";
            });
        });
});
```

I hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Any link to a demo site?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon unfortunately, it is a simple .html file in my computer.

Comment: Well you could try to make a jsfiddle then, the background image shouldnt affect anything if it's missing.

Comment: It would definitely help if you could post a JSFiddle. :)

Comment: Just add a `border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;` to your `ul.menu li`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/CN8ph/

Comment: @abhitalks it works but when I do it, underline is under the menu , not inside the menu. I use my jquery codes to prevent this situation by changing heights of divs. But it doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pure CSS answer to this. There is a lesser known property called `box-sizing` (add browser prefixes for better cross-browser compatibility) . You can check out more in this [post](http://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/) by Chris (CSS-TRICKS) to learn more about it's use & importance.

Now to the Question.

First of all, add a common class for all the `li` tags so that it would reduce the amount of CSS you write. Then, Add a box sizing property with a value of border-box for the common class selector. For Eg, if your common class was `.list`, it would look somewhat like this :-

> .list {    box-sizing:border-box;    }

And then when you hover over the the list tag,

> .list:hover {    border-bottom:3px solid black ; //or whatever color you want    }

I think that should do it.Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xRWw/)  And, I'd recommend you not to use percentages, cause they get distorted if you zoom in or out of the browser.